# Which dependency auto imports struts dependency

Tags: java, maven

I want to remove struts dependency from my repository.It is being auto imported by some other dependency.
I think it is org.apache.velocity but after putting exclusion as well, Maven imports struts. Please help me identify which dependency auto imports struts.

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
 <!-- <packaging>jar</packaging> -->
  <properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties> 


  <profiles>
        <profile>
        <!-- Used only when invoking release:perform so as not to re-run tests as part of the deployment-->
        <id>release</id>
           <activation>
                    <property>
                          <name>env</name>
                          <value>release</value>
                    </property>
           </activation>            
              <properties>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
              </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>     

  <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
              <id>veda.releases</id>
              <name>veda.releases</name>
              <url> http://etp-binrepo.corp.dmz/repository/internal</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
              <id>veda.snapshots</id>
              <name>veda.snapshots</name>
              <url>http://etp-binrepo.corp.dmz/repository/snapshots</url>
              <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
        </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
              <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
              <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
              <artifactId>drools-templates</artifactId>
              <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
              <artifactId>drools-api</artifactId>
              <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.mvel</groupId>
              <artifactId>mvel</artifactId>
              <version>2.0-dp4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
              <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
              <version>1.9.2</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>xerces</groupId>
              <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
              <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
              <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
              <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>log4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
              <version>1.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
              <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
              <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
              <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>junit</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
              <version>4.11</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>jexcelapi</groupId>
              <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
              <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
              <artifactId>xpp3_min</artifactId>
              <version>1.1.3.4.O</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
              <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
              <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
              <artifactId>castor-codegen</artifactId>
              <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
              <artifactId>castor-xml-schema</artifactId>
              <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
              <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
              <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
              <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
              <version>1.6.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                    <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                    <artifactId>struts-tiles</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                    <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
              <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
              <version>2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                    <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                    <artifactId>struts-tiles</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                    <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
              <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
              <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
              <version>3.4.4</version>
        </dependency>       
  </dependencies>
  <build>
        <pluginManagement>
              <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>2.3.1</version>
                          <configuration>
                                <archive>
                                      <manifest>
                                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                            <mainClass>com.veda.evs.app.biz.decision.util.DecisionDriver</mainClass>
                                      </manifest>
                                </archive>
                          </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>2.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                          <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>2.8</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                          <inherited>true</inherited>
                          <configuration>
                                <source>1.8</source>
                                <target>1.8</target>
                          </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                          <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>2.1.2</version>
                          <executions>
                                <execution>
                                      <id>attach-sources</id>
                                      <goals>
                                            <goal>jar</goal>
                                      </goals>
                                </execution>
                          </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                          <artifactId>maven-changelog-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>2.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                          <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>2.3</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                          <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                          <artifactId>jxr-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>2.3</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                          <configuration>
                                <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                          </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>2.8</version>
                          <configuration>
                                <additionalparam>-source 1.6</additionalparam>
                              <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                          </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                          <configuration>
                                <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx512m</argLine>
                                <excludes xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"/>
                                <systemProperties xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
                                      <property>
                                            <name>net.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile</name>
                                            <value>target/cobertura/cobertura.ser</value>
                                      </property>
                                </systemProperties>
                             <excludes/>
           </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>2.1</version>
                          <configuration>
                                <tagBase>http://subversion/repos/ntp/IDMatrix/tags/release/IDM-Decisioning/</tagBase>
                                <goals>deploy -P release</goals>
                          </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                          <configuration>
                                <descriptors>
                                      <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                          </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                          <artifactId>castor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory-->
                    <schema>src/main/resources/xsd/veda-decisioning-schema1.xsd</schema>
                           <packaging>com.veda.evs.app.biz.decision.schema</packaging>
                           <dest>${basedir}/src/main/java</dest>
                           <properties>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/castorbuilder.properties</properties>
                           <bindingfile>src/main/resources/xsd/bindings.xml</bindingfile>
                </configuration>
                    </plugin>
              </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  <reporting>
        <plugins>
              <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <reportSets>
                          <reportSet>
                                <reports>
                                      <report>cim</report>
                                      <report>index</report>
                                      <report>modules</report>
                                      <report>summary</report>
                                      <report>mailing-list</report>
                                      <report>cim</report>
                                      <report>issue-tracking</report>
                                      <report>license</report>
                                      <report>scm</report>
                                </reports>
                          </reportSet>
                    </reportSets>
              </plugin>
              <!-- JavaDoc - API-documentation -->
        <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                    <configuration>
                          <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                          <show>public</show>
                          <charset>utf-8</charset>
                          <docencoding>utf-8</docencoding>
                          <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
              </plugin>
              <!-- Surefire - JUnit testing-->
        <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                <!-- Required to properly link JXR -->
                <xrefLocation>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/../xref-test</xrefLocation>
                    </configuration>
              </plugin>
              <!-- Cobertura - Test code coverage report. -->
        <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                          <formats>
                                <format>xml</format>
                          </formats>
                    </configuration>                
              </plugin>
              <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                          <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                          <xmlOutputDirectory>target</xmlOutputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

Comment: Try using `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` for that

Answer (score 3):

I can't give you a `pom.xml` file with the correct exclusions, but you may try running the following command from your project root folder:

```
man dependency:tree
```

Then, copy the output into a text editor and do a search for `struts`.  If one or more of the other dependencies is bringing it in, you should see that happening.  Then, once you have identified the dependencies which are including it, you may exclude it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Maven is downloading Struts for its own purposes. I know that until fairly recently, the `maven-dependency-plugin` and the `maven-javadoc-plugin` both had Struts as a dependency.

Try temporarily removing all of your own dependencies from the project and see if the problem still happens.

On that point, it would help with answering your question if you could tell us what Maven command reproduces the problem.